# sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database, I get this while opening the app for First time not later

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is my Dbhelperclass, i call dbHeplper.createDataBase() from mainactivity.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.peopleapps.myApp/databases/";
public static String DB_PATH;
public static String DB_NAME = "myDB.sqlite";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TB_USER = "Locations";

private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
private Context context;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);   
    this.context = context;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        Log.e("DB Path",""+DB_PATH);
    }
    else
    {
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        Log.e("DB Path1",""+DB_PATH);
    }

}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDB!=null){
        myDB.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

public Cursor getAllUsers(String sql){
    List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.e("Database",""+db);
    Cursor c=null;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery(sql , null);
        if(c == null) return null;

        String name;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {            
            name = c.getString(0);          
            listUsers.add(name);
        } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        //c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
    }


    //db.close();       

    return c;
}


/***
 * Open database
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Log.e("MyDB",""+myDB);
}

/***
 * Copy database from source code assets to device
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    try {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
        Log.e("myOutPut",""+myOutput);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
    }

}

/***
 * Check if the database doesn't exist on device, create new one
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();      

    if (dbExist) {
        copyDataBase();
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------
// PRIVATE METHODS
// ---------------------------------------------

/***
 * Check if the database is exist on device or not
 * @return
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
    }
    if (tempDB != null)
        tempDB.close();
    return tempDB != null ? true : false;
}


public Cursor fetchLVC(String sql) {
    Cursor mCursor = myDB.rawQuery(sql+" " + TB_USER , null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

}

It throws the following errors

```
E/SQLiteLog(19621): (28) failed to open "/data/data/com.peopleapps.myapp/databases/myDB.sqlite" with flag (131074) and mode_t (0) due to error (2)
E/SQLiteLog(19621): (28) failed to open "/data/data/com.peopleapps.myapp/databases/myDB.sqlite" with flag (131072) and mode_t (0) due to error (2)
E/SQLiteLog(19621): (14) cannot open file at line 32503 of [9491ba7d73]
E/SQLiteLog(19621): (14) os_unix.c:32503: (2) open(/data/data/com.peopleapps.myapp/databases/myDB.sqlite) - 
E/SQLiteDatabase(19621): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.peopleapps.myapp/databases/myDB.sqlite'.
E/SQLiteDatabase(19621): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
E/SQLiteDatabase(19621):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(19621):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:318)
E/SQLiteDatabase(19621):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:228)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

first time application run need create database then :

1-Use openOrCreateDatabase instead openDatabase.

2-Dont forget add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Mainfest.xml.

hope help